# Editing answer not possible - getting no message why

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits

I tried to edit SLaks answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159368/jquery-append-return-appended-elements). I just wanted to correct the name of a function (see my comment on the answer), but as I found out on meta I cannot make edits with less than six characters. Which I understand, because edits should be substantial.

The problem I had was that I didn't know why I couldn't make the edit - I didn't get any message saying I cannot make edits with less than six characters... so I checked meta.

I'm using safari. Is this a known problem?
What should I do when I want to correct minor mistakes like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now. Error messages weren't being shown until the "tag editor" was initialized, and since answers don't have tags, bugginess ensued. Thanks for the report.

Comment: So, should I accept Marc Gravells answer or this one? Don't know how it is supposed to be on meta yet

Comment: Accept this one, @PhilippM. Or just up-vote it. Or both. Or neither. Meta's pretty flexible that way.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, it seems reluctant to show that - it works for questions (below) but not for answers. It is not specific to Safari; I am investigating.

> [image]